# Transporter Can't authorize your user at this time

Tags: itmstransporter

After signing into Transporter get the error message below.

"Can't authorize your user at this time. This action could not be completed due to possible environment mismatch (-29004)"

I have tried all the fixes mentioned here for similar errors and on the apple support forum but none work for me.

Any advice would be great.

Have logged a support ticket with apple dev waiting for a reply, I'm interested if others are experiencing this error with Transporter.

Apple mini M1 2020
macOS Monterey
Ver. 12.5

Comment: I've had no luck with this login problem. I am also waiting for Apple support. However, I switched to command line tools and they worked:

`xcrun altool --upload-app --type ios -f app.ipa -u developeraccountuser@company.com -p app-specific-password`

I created the app specific password at https://appleid.apple.com.